# How to redirect to another view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2. I have a simple form on the homepage. When a user clicks search on that form it should send them to a registration page. It's just a dummy form so no data is being submitted. I'm not sure what I need to put in my routes file. Do I need to put something in my controllers file as well? Any help will be appreciated.

This is what I have on my main page...

```
form action="{{route('register')}}" method="post"
```

Comment: Do you need just simple form submit and redirect to another url or something like if you are not logged in, to redirect you to register page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to go to the "register" page when the form is submitted. Why would you want to do that? Though if you want to do that, @Vinicius answer is correct. I think what you want is - **"If my users are logged in, then do the search, instead go to the register page"**.

To do what I am proposing, you will have to categorize your routes in [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware).

So in your routes file, you will define this route.

```
Route::post('search', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    return view('search');
}]);
```

This route will make sure that the "search functionality" method is only accessible when you are logged in. If laravel finds that the user is not logged in, it will automatically redirect the user to the `register` page.

For more information look at this [code](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php). This is the middleware functionality which decides if the user is logged in or not. As you can see, laravel by default will redirect the user to the login page. For you to redirect user to the register page, change the line to this.

```
return redirect()->guest('register');
```

Comment: Your way would work but If a user is already logged in, I will want them to be redirected to there dashboard once that is setup.

Comment: @Slillz I am sorry but I am a little confused. What do you want to happen when the form is submitted? If a user is logged in and submits the search form, you want them to just search. Users redirecting to their dashboard is a different question which I will answer once we have solved your current query..

Comment: All I want to happen is that when a user who is not signed into the site clicks the search button on the welcome view,  the user gets redirected the register view.  In the future once I design he dashboard, if a user is already signed in they will be redirected to the dashboard view but that's down the line.

Comment: @Slillz Well isn't that my answer? If the user is not signed in, they will be redirected to "register" page, and if they are logged in, they will "complete" the request i.e. will go wherever the post action has said it to go. So your form action will in future will point to "dashboard".

Comment: Correct. I used your logic but for some reason I'm getting an error..............Not Found

The requested URL /register was not found on this server.

Comment: Are you sure you have added the `register` route in your routes.php file? Don't forget to check the complete URL you are calling. e.g. `localhost/myproject/public/register` instead of just `localhost/register`

Comment: In my route file I have the following....Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('welcome');
        });

Route::get('register', function () {
  return view('register');
        })->name('register');

Comment: To access the website homepage I use... laravel.sitename.com.

Comment: I have the welcome and register view in the same folder.

Comment: Here is the routes.php code...  Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('welcome');
        });

Route::get('/register', function () {
  return view('views.register');
        })->name('register');

Comment: @Slillz 2 things: 1. register route is only accessible by GET method. 2. Register view is placed inside the `view` folder. So make sure that register is really present inside the view folder.

Comment: Yes I'm using a GET method. I even just created a regular anchor link on the welcome view and got the same error. The two views are actually in the same folder. Welcome and register are in a folder called "views". The path is "var/www/laravel/resources/views"....I was just trying something out. This is how the routes.php file looks....Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('welcome');
        });

Route::get('register', function () {
  return view('register');
        })->name('register');

Comment: @Slillz From the looks of your structure you need to create another `views` folder inside the `resources/views` folder. Laravel by default is inside the `resources/views` folder and is expected another view folder inside it. Or simple change the `views.register` to only `register` in the routes file.

Comment: Yes I changed it to only register and still getting that error.

Comment: @Slillz When you hover over the GET link of register, can you paste that URL in here? The mistake is definitely of path here.

Comment: @Slillz I was reading back your comments and one of your comments mentioned you defined routes like `Route::get('register', ... `. So you may have missed the `/` here. Try `Route::get('/register', ... ' instead. Sorry but I have no more suggestions to give. Its somewhere a silly mistake. I am sure you will find it if you do it again from scratch.

Comment: Yes adding that slash did work. One more question. In my routes.php there is a middleware function below my routes. Should my routes go under that...                                                                                                                             Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('welcome');
        });

Route::get('/register', function () {
  return view('register');
        });/*})->name('register');

Route::get('register', [
  'uses' => 'Controller@register',
  'as' => 'register'
        ]);*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
});

Comment: @Slillz See I told you it would be a stupid mistake ;) All your routes will go in the `auth` middleware function which require user to be authenticated. So you don't need to define your GET routes above that middleware. Move the entire register route inside that middleware.

Comment: @Slillz Please don't forget to support my answer if you like it.

Comment: I moved them below but the same result.

Comment: @Slillz Since we have already fixed the problem, the reason for not running again seems to be that you have not written the middleware correctly. Please go through the middleware document I linked earlier and redo your code.

Comment: I read the middleware early but I haven't even created users yet so that wouldn't come into play yet.

Comment: @Slillz It does not matter if you have created users or not. You are using the `web` middleware which no doubt you created. All I am saying is that you might not have put your routes correctly in the middleware, hence the error.

Comment: The issue didn't have anything to do with Middleware. I had to run "sudo a2enmod rewrite" on the server and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add a redirect statement with the form view, some like this, in your routes file:

```
Route::post('register' , function(){
    return view('register.form');
});
```

You can add this return statement into a controller, and your route file will be something like this:

```
Route::post('register' , 'YourControllerName@register');
```

And your controller:

```
public function register(){
    return view('register.form');
}
```

Comment: After making the changes you  suggested, I'm now getting an error message...                                                                                            'Route [register] not defined. (View: /var/www/laravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php).'                            It seems to be something with this form action because when I remove {{route('register')}} from this '<form action="{{route('register')}}" method="post">' and leave it empty. The error goes away.

Comment: in your route file you can do this:
Route::post('register' ,  ['as' => 'register' , 'uses' => 'YourControllerName@register']);
maybe it can resolve your problems with {{ route('register') }}

Comment: the first argument is the URI that will appear in your browser, 'as' is an alias to this route and 'uses' is the action to this route (Your controller)

Comment: Not getting the error anymore but it's says the following when i click search on the form....Not Found

The requested URL /register was not found on this server.                                  I changed method on the form to "Get".. The following is what I have in my routes file. I don't anything in my controller. I should work this I think....Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('welcome');
        });

Route::get('register', function () {
  return view('register');
        })->name('register');

Comment: @ViniciusLuiz First - This is not a redirect method, and direct call a view in post method route not good idea, when you hit in address bar it produce error to get method not allowed.